# Using sftp to Transfer a Directory?

Tags: bash, command-line, ftp, sftp

When I try to use SFTP to transfer a directory containing files, I get an error message:

```
skipping non-regular file directory_name
```

The directory contains a couple of files and two subdirectories.

What am I doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use the -r parameter.

```
 -r      Recursively copy entire directories.  Note that scp follows sym‐
         bolic links encountered in the tree traversal.
```